# Why am I getting http-error when trying to delete a datomic db?

Tags: datomic

I tried to delete a datomic database inside the datomic repl. I have the transactor and peer-server running, and am using the client api. Here's what I did in the repl:

```
(require '[clojure.core.async :refer [<!!]]
         '[datomic.client :as client])

(use 'datomic.client.admin)

(pprint (<!! (delete-database 
    {:db-name "datemo"
     :account-id client/PRO_ACCOUNT
     :secret "datemo"
     :region "none"
     :endpoint "localhost:8998"
     :service "peer-server"
     :access-key "datemo"})))
```

The error I get looks like this:

```
{:cognitect.anomalies/category :cognitect.anomalies/incorrect,
 :datomic.client/http-error {:cause "Invalid Op"}}
```

The [docs for the datomic client](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure-client/index.html#datomic.client.admin/delete-database) call for an map of arguments, which is what is provided above. They also seem to suggest that the required argument is `:db-name`, but if I do something like:

```
(pprint (<!! (delete-database {:db-name "datemo"})))
```

I get an error saying that the "connection config" is invalid:

```
#:cognitect.anomalies{:category :cognitect.anomalies/incorrect,
                      :message
                      "Incomplete or invalid connection config: {:timeout 60000, :account-id \"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\", :access-key \"datemo\", :secret \"datemo\", :endpoint \"localhost:8998\", :service \"peer-server\", :region nil, :db-name \"datemo\"}"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from person in the know:

> Peerserver can’t delete or create databases. Since a single peerserver could be connected to multiple transactors/backend storages at once the semantics aren’t clear what ‘create’ would mean - which backend should it use for example?

Answer (score 1):

The client API cannot create and delete databaseses as peer servers do not own databases.  The client API talks to peer servers and as a result the client API does not create or delete.  You will want to use the peer library to create or delete.

http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/delete-database
http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/create-database

The local dev setup tutorial in the Datomic docs uses the peer api and there are also examples using the peer api in the day of datomic examples:

http://docs.datomic.com/dev-setup.html#create-db
https://github.com/Datomic/day-of-datomic